# Why receiver.tell(msg, sender) but not sender.tell(msg, receiver) in akka?

Tags: java, akka

I'm a beginner on akka.
Could someone explain to me why the **tell** method defined like this:

```
receiver.tell(msg, sender);
```

In my mind, someone sends a message to other people, in OOP it would like:

```
sender.tell(msg, receiver)
```

**Sender tell a message to the receiver**

Comment: Post relevant questions based on your use case. Explain about your use case and then ask questions on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to explain this with an example.

**Section 1:**

Just think of this as a text messaging between two persons(For example **A** and **B**).

If **A** receives a message from **B**, then `A is the Receiver` and `B is the Sender`. Suppose, if A sends a message, then, `A becomes the Sender` whereas `B becomes Receiver`

So, the sender and receiver really depends on the direction of flow of the message. Both will act as a Sender and Receiver.

Coming to your example..

The `ActorRef` passed as the second parameter in `tell()` method denotes who sent the message whereas the `ActorRef` who's `tell` method been called is the Receiver.

Generally it is like `Reciever.tell(message, sender)` in both places. But, you might refer it as `Sender.tell(msg, receiver)` as an indication of replying to the Actor who sent the message in the first place.

Even though you say it as `Sender.tell(msg, receiver)`, here `Sender` part is the one who is going to receive the message and `Receiver` part is the one who actually sends the message(Replying in this case).

*Try to read and understand above line by line, as it may seem confusing. Then continue below.*

---

**Section 2:**

Now, in `Reciever.tell(message, sender)` the sender need not always be the one who sent the message. It can point to some other actor also. Or it can have no actor at all by simply passing `ActorRef.noSender()`.

Now consider there are three actors **A**,**B** & **C**. 
If I sent a message from A actor to B actor as below,

```
B.tell(message, C);
```

In B's Context, C will be the one who sent the message to B eventhough A was the actual sender. So, when you send reply as below,

```
getSender().tell(replyMsg, getSelf());
```

Here, `getSender()` method will return reference to Actor C instead of Actor A. So, Actor C will receive the reply message.

If suppose, Actor A sent a message with no sender reference at all as below,

```
B.tell(message, ActorRef.noSender())
```

Then in B's context, there will be no sender. The sender is unknown. Suppose if B tries to send reply `getSender().tell(replyMsg, getSelf())` then **no user actors(A,B,C) will receive the message** but will be delivered to a special type of system actor known as `deadLetter` actor.